# how to disable href depending on session

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, href

i m stuck in a position where i cant find any solution

i have a link and button here is the code im saving the page in db so i cannot create a server control as it will not render it

```
    <div id="DivCMS" runat="server"></div>// i use this in server side

//this code is saved in db table CMS_Pages//////begin
     <a href="User/Register.aspx" id="alinkRegister" >
    <img src="App_Themes/White/Images/getstarted.png" style="padding-left: 117px;" />
    </a>
//this code is saved in db table CMS_Pages//////end
```

on page load i fill div with data from db

```
if (!IsPostBack){
                var cp = new CMS_Pages();//Data Access block
                cp.LoadByPrimaryKey(12);// load data
                LiteralControl Ref = new LiteralControl(cp.PageHeader);
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(Ref);
                DivCMS.InnerHtml = cp.PageHtml;}
```

how can i disable href according to session in javascript ie

```
if (session["UserId"] !=null) then href=# <br>
else href="User/register.aspx"
```

Comment: You can't access the session directly from javascript. Youn can show a hidden input on the page if the user is logged in. Better you can directly show in ASP the right href.

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace it to # if has a session

```
if (session["UserId"] != null) 
{
    cp.PageHtml=cp.PageHtml.Replace("User/Register.aspx","#");
}
```